# How to verify a Postgres database is SSL enabled?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, openssl, tls1.2, tls1.3

I am trying to setup SSL on a postgres database instance. Tested using self-signed certificates. Here are the steps which I followed:

1. openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 2048
2. openssl req -x509 -new -key rootCA.key -days 1000 -out rootCA.crt
3. openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
4. openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
5. chmod 600 server.key
6. openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 500
7. Modified the parameters in the postgresql.conf file:

```
ssl = on
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
ssl_cert_key = 'server.key'
```

8. Next, modified the pg_hba.conf file. Changed reference of host to hostssl

```
local      all             all                                  md5
hostssl    all             all             127.0.0.1/32         md5
hostssl    all             all             ::1/128              md5 
local   replication     all                                     md5
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
hostssl all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

9. Restarted the database instance.

Now, when I try to connect to the database, this prompt comes up:

```
[user@user_vm~]$ psql -U postgres -d testdb -h localhost
psql (13.7)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

testdb=#
```

Though, in the prompt the SSL connection comes up, I am not really sure whether the database is SSL enabled or not? This is because the output does not change even if the sslmode is set to 'require'.

Am I missing something or have some wrong understanding about the encryption setup? Any help/insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is offtopic as unrelated to software programming, but I believe this table in PostgreSQL documentation explains in detail what `sslmode` implies for each of its values: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-ssl.html#LIBPQ-SSL-SSLMODE-STATEMENTS ; note in particular the default value being `prefer` and the text explaining how it does not make sense in a security minded deployment.

Comment: Which output would you expect to change when sslmode is set to 'require', and why?